# Automatically updating a date field in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2007

So I'm trying to build an app for a builder to give new estimates to customers.

One of the features is that when he tries to create a new estimate, the quote date will get automatically get filled with the date of when the estimate is created.

And then a second date field is auto-filled to be 30 days later, so the builder can know when the quote expires. See below:

[image]

As you can see, the date fields in the Access table is not filled in.

However, it works when you change the date manually using the date picker and set it to something other than the default, see below:

[image]

now it shows up.

Here's the code I used to automatically set the dates of the date picker:

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Adds today's date to the quote date as a defalut
        QuoteDateDateTimePicker.Value = Date.Today

        ' Creates automatic expiry date for quote in 30 days
        QuoteExpiryDateTimePicker.Value = Date.Today.AddDays(30D)
```

When I press the save button I expected the data would be added to the table.
Save button:

```
' Save Quote
Private Sub btnSaveEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveEdit.Click
    ' This causes the Total button to be clicked so that when 
    ' users try to save the quote without pressing the "total" 
    ' button it doesn't save an empty quote.
    btnTotal_Click(sender, e)

    ' Save quote
    QuotesBindingSource.EndEdit()
    If TotalTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a some estimates")
    End If
    QuotesTableAdapter.Update(QuotesDataSet.quotes)
    End Sub
```

Comment: What's in the btnTotal_Click event?

Comment: @programmer95 That's the Total button at the bottom of the page, when someone presses the save button I trigger the Total button, so that costs, sub total, VAT etc are calculated before being saved to the table.